# Running Threads and Controlling Them

Tags: java, multithreading

I need help figuring out how to code this problem I am running into.

I'm creating an elevator simulator. I want to run each Elevator object in separate individual threads. I want to control them with my ElevatorController object. I am imagining the Elevator threads sitting in IDLE and then switching to UP or DOWN when the ElevatorController tells it to.

I have created the Elevators and put them into an ArrayList that is stored in the Building object.

What do I do next? My objective is to make elevator1 go to Floor 11. While elevator1 is moving I need to tell elevator2 to go to Floor 14. As elevator2 is moving to Floor 14, I need to tell it to go to Floor 13 first.

I'm unsure how I am supposed to create these threads and still have a reference to the elevator objects in these threads, so I can tell them the new destination.

I'm new to multithreading.

Comment: "I want to run each Elevator object in separate individual threads"  Why?  Is this an exercise to learn about synchronizing threads? or is it an exercise to learn about real-time control and simulation?  If I were asked to simulate a bank of elevators, I probably would _not_ have a thread per elevator.  I would model an entire bank of elevators (including their controller) in a single event-driven thread with a time-ordered event queue.

Answer (score 0):

Define each thread as a field in your `building` so you can access it later. I would do something like:

```
public class ElevatorThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(!this.interrupted()) {
            synchronized(this) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            elevatorThreadRunnable.run();
        }
    }
    Runnable elevatorThreadRunnable;
    public void setRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        elevatorThreadRunnable = runnable;
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

If we define the `ElevatorThread`s as an array it gets even easier. We can simply:

```
building.elevatorThreads[0].setRunnable(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Where:

```
//I belong in the Building constructor!
Thread[] elevatorThreads = {
    new ElevatorThread(),
    new ElevatorThread(),
    new ElevatorThread()
    //number of elevators in building
    /*
        this could be simplified to a method that takes the number of threads as an int
        and returns an inflated array, but that is outside the context of this answer
    */
};
```

If we do this, our `Runnable` is ran in the elevator thread of your choosing. The thread will also idle like you requested, until a new `Runnable` is set.

To kill a thread, we call `ElevatorThread.interrupt();`, this will cause the thread to stop `wait()`ing if it is, and then break out of our execution loop; killing the thread.

Comment: thank you very much. I think I understand what you are saying and I will try to go implement this.

Comment: Are you sure this can't be partly achieved using the executors framework added in Java 6?

Comment: @Adam, it probably can. There is often multiple working approaches to accomplish a goal. I am admittedly not familiar with executors. You could perhaps write an answer with use of executors to share the knowledge.